# How to refresh a databound TreeView?

Tags: wpf, xml, treeview, refresh, data-binding

I have two TreeView´s in a TabControl, databound to a xmlDataProvider. If i add nodes to my Xml and save it:

```
xmlDataProvider.Document.Save(fullPathToXml);
xmlDataProvider.Refresh();
```

Only the TreeView that is not in the open Tab refresh. Both TreeView´s look like this:

```
<TreeView Name="DIFFERENT_NAMES" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataxml}, XPath=./*}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ItemsSource is binded to a property implementing OnPropertyChanged, you can add the attribute "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanges" to your binding in the XAML.
Hence, the control will update itself each time OnPropertyChanged is called

**EDIT**

I assume your ViewModel already implements OnPropertyChanged
Therefore, all you have to do is, when you declare your property:

```
private XmlDataProvider _xmlDataProvider;
public XmlDataProvider XmlDataProvider
        {
            get { return xmlDataProvider; }
            set 
            { 
                xmlDataProvider = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("XmlDataProvider");
            }
        }
```

Initialize the XmlDataProvider in your constructor, and then, each time the object is modified, it will call the method OnPropertyChanged, on the property you specify (here "XmlDataProvider"), and each time OnPropertyChanged is called, your view bound to this object will refresh automatically :)

Comment: I have added the property to the TreeView but nothing changed. How can i implementing the OnPropertyChange to my ItemSource? My Source: XmlDataProvider xmlDataProvider = new XmlDataProvider();

Comment: Just edited my post with a code snippet of what you should add, if not already added :)